# possible conflicting javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am basically completely thrown off and think I may have some conflicting JavaScript, which might explain why the help I have been getting from everyone here hasn't been successful. Basically - the background color doesn't change when the links with id's #pagename2 & #pagename3 and I wish to hide the div #black until a nav option is clicked...

Alot of my post is JavaScript but if anyone has any time, I would be eternally grateful! -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Steve A Tattoo Artist | Just another WordPress site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--[if lt ie 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/styles/ie7.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt ie 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/styles/ie6.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/xmlrpc.php" />

<!------- DEMO CSS LINKS --------->
<link href="http:/www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!------- MAIN NAV SLIDER --------->
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.scrollTo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.localscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.serialScroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.compatibility.js"></script>

<!------- FANCY BOX REFS --------->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!------- COLOR CHANGER --------->
<script>
$("#secondpagename, #thirdpagename").click(function(e){
 $("#blackandwhite").css(backgroundColor: '#000000');
    e.preventDefault()
});
</script>

<!------- FANCY BOX JAVA --------->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
/* This is basic - uses default settings */
$("a#single_image").fancybox();

/* Using custom settings */
$("a#inline").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});

/* Apply fancybox to multiple items */  
$("a.group").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false
});
});
</script> 

<!------- MAIN SLIDER JAVA --------->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".bgcolor").click(function() {
$("#blackandwhite").css(backgroundColor: '#000000');
});

var $scroll = $('#slider .scroll');
$('#slider .navigation').find('a').click(selectNav);
function selectNav() {
  $(this)
    .parents('ul:first') // find the first UL parent
      .find('a') // find all the A elements
        .removeClass('selected') // remove from all
      .end() // go back to all A elements
    .end() // go back to 'this' element
    .addClass('selected');
}
function trigger(data) {
  var el = $('#slider .navigation').find('a[href$="' + data.id + '"]').get(0);
  selectNav.call(el);
}
if (window.location.hash) {
  trigger({ id : window.location.hash.substr(1)});
} else {
  $('#slider .navigation a:first').click();
}
//--document
var $panels = $('#slider .scrollContainer > div');
var $container = $('#slider .scrollContainer');

// if false, we'll float all the panels left and fix the width 
// of the container
var horizontal = true;

// float the panels left if we're going horizontal
if (horizontal) {
  $panels.css({
    'float' : 'left',
    'position' : 'relative' // IE fix to ensure overflow is hidden
  });

  // calculate a new width for the container (so it holds all panels)
  $container.css('width', $panels[0].offsetWidth * $panels.length);
}

// collect the scroll object, at the same time apply the hidden overflow
// to remove the default scrollbars that will appear
var $scroll = $('#slider .scroll').css('overflow', 'hidden');

// apply our left + right buttons
$scroll
  .before('<img class="scrollButtons left" src="images/scroll_left.png" />')
  .after('<img class="scrollButtons right" src="images/scroll_right.png" />');

// handle nav selection
function selectNav() {
  $(this)
    .parents('ul:first')
      .find('a')
        .removeClass('selected')
      .end()
    .end()
    .addClass('selected');
}

$('#slider .navigation').find('a').click(selectNav);

// go find the navigation link that has this target and select the nav
function trigger(data) {
 var el = $('#slider .navigation').find('a[href$="' + data.id + '"]').get(0);
selectNav.call(el);
}

if (window.location.hash) {
trigger({ id : window.location.hash.substr(1) });
} else {
$('ul.navigation a:first').click();
}

// offset is used to move to *exactly* the right place, since I'm using
// padding on my example, I need to subtract the amount of padding to
// the offset.  Try removing this to get a good idea of the effect
var offset = parseInt((horizontal ? 
$container.css('paddingTop') : 
$container.css('paddingLeft')) 
|| 0) * -1;


var scrollOptions = {
target: $scroll, // the element that has the overflow

// can be a selector which will be relative to the target
items: $panels,

navigation: '.navigation a',

// selectors are NOT relative to document, i.e. make sure they're unique
prev: 'img.left', 
next: 'img.right',

// allow the scroll effect to run both directions
  axis: 'xy',

onAfter: trigger, // our final callback

offset: offset,

// duration of the sliding effect
duration: 1500,

easing: 'swing'
};

// apply serialScroll to the slider - we chose this plugin because it 
// supports// the indexed next and previous scroll along with hooking 
// in to our navigation.
$('#slider').serialScroll(scrollOptions);

// now apply localScroll to hook any other arbitrary links to trigger 
// the effect
$.localScroll(scrollOptions);

// finally, if the URL has a hash, move the slider in to position, 
// setting the duration to 1 because I don't want it to scroll in the
// very first page load.  We don't always need this, but it ensures
// the positioning is absolutely spot on when the pages loads.
scrollOptions.duration = 1;
$.localScroll.hash(scrollOptions);

});

</script>

<!------- MAIN TOP NAV SCROLLING --------->

<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 591) {
        $(".altstevenav:hidden").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".altstevenav:visible").hide();
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 591) {
        $(".topwhiteborder:hidden").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".topwhiteborder:visible").hide();
    }
});
</script>

<!------- END OF DEMO CSS LINKS --------->

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Steve A Tattoo Artist &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/?feed=rss2" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Steve A Tattoo Artist &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/?feed=comments-rss2" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery.fancybox-css'  href='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/plugins/fancy-box/jquery.fancybox.css?ver=1.2.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css?ver=20111209' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/plugins/fancy-box/jquery.fancybox.js?ver=1.2.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/plugins/fancy-box/jquery.easing.js?ver=1.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.3.1" />

<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/' />
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var select = $('a[href$=".bmp"],a[href$=".gif"],a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".jpeg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".BMP"],a[href$=".GIF"],a[href$=".JPG"],a[href$=".JPEG"],a[href$=".PNG"]');
        select.attr('rel', 'fancybox');
        select.fancybox();
    });
</script>
    <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
</head>
<body class="home page page-id-2 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar">
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">              

<div class="simage"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/skull.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="stitle">The <span style="color:#ffc600; font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;">Illustrated Man</span> II</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="squote">&quot;We are all tattooed in our cradles with the beliefs of our tribe; the record may seem superficial, but it is indelible.&quot;</div>

<!--------------------------------------------------->
<!------------------ POP UP MENU -------------------->
<div class="altstevenav" style="display:none">
<div class="stevenav">
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="#firstpagename">Steve A</a></li>

<li><a href="#secondpagename" class="bgcolor">Tattoos</a></li>
<li><a href="#thirdpagename" class="bgcolor">Sketchbook</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div> <!------------------------ MAIN CLOSING DIV --------------------------->
</div> <!------------------------ CONTENT CLOSING DIV --------------------------->

<div id="slider">
<div class="delstevenav">
<div class="stevenav">
<ul class="navigation">

<li><a href="#firstpagename" class="bgcolor">Steve A</a></li>
<li><a href="#secondpagename" class="bgcolor">Tattoos</a></li>
<li><a href="#thirdpagename" class="bgcolor">Sketchbook</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="black">
<div style="width:968px; margin: 0 auto;">

<!--------------------------------------------------->
<!-------------- SLDIER AND MAIN MENU --------------->

<!------------------- element with overflow applied ------------------->

<div class="scroll">
<!---------------- the element that will be scrolled during the effect -------------->
<div class="scrollContainer">
<!----------------- our individual panels ----------------->

<div class="panel" id="firstpagename" style="color:#000000;">
<div style="width:515px; float:left;">
<img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/bio-pic1.jpg" width="425" alt="Biography Image" />
<br /><br />
<img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/bio-pic2.jpg" width="425" alt="Biography Image" />
<br /><br />
<img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/bio-pic3.jpg" width="425" alt="Biography Image" />
</div>
<div style="width:350px; float:left; text-align:left;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam non lorem quam, at posuere lectus. Phasellus et est eget nisl vulputate sodales ut vel mi. Cras non orci nisl. Cras non mi suscipit tellus porta iaculis at consequat nulla.Phasellus bibendum rhoncus risus, placerat posuere est interdum in. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam laoreet libero quis enim iaculis et aliquam ligula molestie. Integer luctus vulputate interdum. Vivamus pulvinar neque et nunc porttitor dictum.<br />

<br />
Ut commodo nibh vitae augue consectetur molestie. Vestibulum quis metus eros. Suspendisse vel arcu mi, at placerat lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur vehicula quam non lorem sodales nec pellentesque elit imperdiet. Fusce non orci dolor. Nunc id velit diam.<br />
<br />
Integer facilisis arcu ut leo eleifend sagittis. Aliquam erat volutpat. In eu iaculis sem. Fusce non diam et purus pulvinar varius quis a ligula. Maecenas tortor mi, mattis vitae tincidunt sit amet, lobortis a metus. Aenean vitae laoreet sem. Nullam quis turpis neque. Donec dapibus dignissim ligula ac feugiat. Proin mi lorem, sagittis at sollicitudin sit amet, rhoncus a odio. Fusce malesuada enim a diam consequat rhoncus. Mauris venenatis arcu a nulla tempor quis venenatis velit semper. Integer a tortor gravida nibh bibendum accumsan in vitae turpis. Etiam ac purus sit amet diam feugiat commodo non eget felis. Vestibulum magna magna, laoreet accumsan accumsan eget, hendrerit vitae arcu.<br />
<br />
Etiam sed lacus sed nulla pharetra viverra. Praesent dapibus nibh eleifend sapien viverra sagittis. Curabitur tempor auctor erat, ut blandit lacus accumsan vitae. Donec a risus vel purus accumsan sollicitudin ut at massa. Aenean elementum urna quis massa convallis eu luctus massa lacinia. Proin nisl metus, mollis a laoreet nec, tempor a mauris. Pellentesque a erat metus. Suspendisse quis vulputater diam. Mauris turpis sapien, sagittis id vehicula sit amet, fringilla a mi. Phasellus id orci et purus tincidunt facilisis eu sit amet nulla. Sed id magna vitae quam feugiat tempus. Donec vel mauris eu ligula aliquet rutrum ut in nisl. Vivamus ut viverra mi. Donec ut porta eros. Aliquam molestie turpis tempus tortor aliquam fringilla. Nam vitae nisi urna.<br />
<br />
Proin hendrerit interdum erat, vitae varius dui mollis id. Proin vitae lorem a ante mollis euismod et id ante. Etiam sit amet urna quis diam egestas rutrum non sit amet arcu. Sed est nulla, rhoncus eget molestie in, pulvinar eget lorem. Suspendisse sit amet tortor est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus dolor sapien, euismod a tristique in, faucibus vitae sem. Proin ipsum nunc, consectetur vitae mollis in, condimentum non tortor. In ultrices adipiscing ligula ut fringilla. Nullam ultrices tempus lorem euismod elementum. Quisque aliquet sollicitudin vulputate. Nullam id faucibus libero. Aenean sodales pellentesque sagittis. Vestibulum dignissim fermentum nibh, ut interdum magna fringilla eu. Donec luctus condimentum purus eu porta.</div>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="secondpagename" style="background-color:#000000; color:#FFFFFF;">
<p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

2Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
</p>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="thirdpagename" style="background-color:#000000; color:#FFFFFF;">
<p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
3Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
</p>
</div>

</div></div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
<!---------------------------------------------------------->

<!-------------- END OF SLDIER AND MAIN MENU --------------->

<div style="display:none"><div id="data"><h2>Contact Steve A</h2><p></p></p></div></div>
<div style="display:none"><div id="copy" style="width:400px;"><h2>Copyright Information:</h2><p><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#8217;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</p></div></div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.js?ver=20111130'></script>
        <div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs" role="navigation">
            <div class="quicklinks">
                <ul id="wp-admin-bar-root-default" class="ab-top-menu">

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/about.php" title="About WordPress"><span class="ab-icon"></span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-about" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/about.php">About WordPress</a>       </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-external" class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://wordpress.org">WordPress.org</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://codex.wordpress.org">Documentation</a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forums</a>      </li>

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback">Feedback</a>       </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-site-name" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/">Steve A Tattoo Artist</a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-site-name-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-dashboard" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a>      </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-appearance" class=" ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-themes" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/themes.php">Themes</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-widgets" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/widgets.php">Widgets</a>       </li>

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-menus" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Menus</a>     </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-updates" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/update-core.php" title="1 Plugin Update"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">1</span></a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-comments" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php" title="0 comments awaiting moderation"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span id="ab-awaiting-mod" class="ab-label awaiting-mod pending-count count-0">0</span></a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-content" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/post-new.php" title="Add New"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">New</span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-new-content-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-post" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/post-new.php">Post</a>        </li>

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-media" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/media-new.php">Media</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-link" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/link-add.php">Link</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-page" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page">Page</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-user" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/user-new.php">User</a>        </li></ul></div>        </li>

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&#038;action=edit">Edit Page</a>       </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-search" class=" admin-bar-search"><div class="ab-item ab-empty-item" tabindex="-1"><form action="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch"><input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" tabindex="10" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" /><input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search"/></form></div>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account" class="menupop with-avatar"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/profile.php" title="My Account">Howdy, clairewild<img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/63344d548f5d2204635a85802d53cf97?s=16&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D16&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-16 photo' height='16' width='16' /></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-user-actions" class=" ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-user-info" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/profile.php"><img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/63344d548f5d2204635a85802d53cf97?s=64&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D64&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-64 photo' height='64' width='64' /><span class='display-name'>clairewild</span></a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit-profile" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/profile.php">Edit My Profile</a>      </li>

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-logout" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=9295d2f263">Log Out</a>     </li></ul></div>        </li></ul>          </div>
        </div>


<div class="menu">
<div class="middle">
<ul style="margin-top:6px;">
<li><a id="inline" href="#data">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.steve-a.co.uk/">The Illustrated Man I</a></li>

<li><a href="http://www.indelible-tattoo.co.uk/">Indeliable Tattoo Studio</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.bournemouthtattooconvention.com/artists.php">Bournemouth Tattoo Convention</a></li>
</ul>
<ul style="margin-top:5px;">
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1805246243"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/fb.jpg" height="17" width="16" alt="facebook icon for steveatattooartist" /></a></li>
<li><a id="inline" href="#copy"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/copyright.jpg" height="17" width="17" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>


</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

That is my source code, alternatively the link to the site can be found here:
http://steveatattooartist.com

Comment: You have **FOUR** different major versions of jQuery being loaded there! Pick one and make the code compatible with it!

Comment: Your site isn't valid [HTML 4.01 Strict](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.steveatattooartist.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Try to provide a [sscc example](http://sscce.org/). @Quentin: Four? That's like killing kittens on purpose oO. It's cruel, horrid, gross and absolute unnecessary. OP, choose *one*.

Comment: 1.2, 1.3, 1.5 and 1.7 that I can see. Looks worryingly like copy/pasting without understanding.

Comment: [JavaScript is not Java.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, why are you including jQuery from 3 different locations/versions?

Try removing :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This should just leave you with the 1.5 reference, which 'may' help things along

Answer (score 2):

Well, at first sight at the javascript console, the lines with this code are not correct:

```
$("#blackandwhite").css(backgroundColor: '#000000');
```

**Correct syntax** is either `.css( propertyName, value )` like this:

```
$("#blackandwhite").css('backgroundColor', '#000000');
```

or an object literal `.css( map )` like this (note the `{ }`):

```
$("#blackandwhite").css( { backgroundColor: '#000000' } );
```

[**jQuery .css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, the jQuery loaded with Wordpress uses "no conflict" mode, so you can't use `$()` you'll have to use `jQuery()` or put a closure around the code like

```
(function ($) { 
    // code goes here 
})(jQuery)
```